# How to unescape double-escaped string in Python?

Tags: python, string, escaping

I have the following string `"Supplements\\/General Health"`, where the "/" was already escaped, but unfortunately got escaped again and an additional "\" was added.

In the task that I have I can't do anything about the double escaping, so I need to work with the input `"Supplements\\/General Health"`, but I would like to unescape it and split it.

I want to end up with `"Supplements/General Health"`.


I tried:

```
>>> "Supplements\\/General Health".encode("utf-8").decode("unicode-escape")
'Supplements\\/General Health'
```

and it does nothing.

What else can I try?

Comment: try this `"Supplements\\/General Health".replace("\\", "", 1)`

Comment: What you're looking at isn't a *Unicode escape* or anything else to do with *encoding*, so yeah, that approach doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `.replace()`:

```
s = r"Supplements\\/General Health"
print(s.replace(r"\\", ""))
```

Comment: Yes, but this will remove any and all backslashes, even if they were *meant* to be in the text…